# Is java.lang.Math compatible with kotlin.math?

Tags: math, kotlin, rounding, java

I was learning `Kotlin` and ran into this issue in Math class:

The `java.lang.Math` and `kotlin.math` are not compatible. This is for me a little bit awkward and confusing since `Kotlin` claims that it is 100% compatible with `Java`. Maybe this is only me who is feeling it is confusing, but I would like to hear community opinion to confirm if my feeling is correct.

The issue is the rounding of a number. Please observe the following simple `Kotlin` code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val neg = -152.5
val kotlinAbsoluteValue = kotlin.math.abs(neg)
val javaAbsoluteValue = java.lang.Math.abs(neg)
println("Original Variable: $neg")
println("Absolute Value in Java: $javaAbsoluteValue")
println("Absolute Value in Kotlin: $kotlinAbsoluteValue")
println("Rounding kotlinAbsoluteValue in Java: ${java.lang.Math.round(kotlinAbsoluteValue)}")
println("Rounding kotlinAbsoluteValue in Kotlin: ${kotlin.math.round(kotlinAbsoluteValue)}")
println("Rounding javaAbsoluteValue in Java: ${java.lang.Math.round(javaAbsoluteValue)}")
println("Rounding javaAbsoluteValue in Kotlin ${kotlin.math.round(javaAbsoluteValue)}")
}
```

Output:

```
Original Variable: -152.5
Absolute Value in Java: 152.5
Absolute Value in Kotlin: 152.5
Rounding kotlinAbsoluteValue in Java: 153
Rounding kotlinAbsoluteValue in Kotlin: 152.0
Rounding javaAbsoluteValue in Java: 153
Rounding javaAbsoluteValue in Kotlin 152.0
```

I see that Java Math is rounding up to `long` value and Kotlin in contrast rounding down to `kotlin.Double` value. The implementation of Math classes in two different languages are different and wouldn't this cause confusion since they both target JVM?

Thanks

Comment: Kotlin is 100% compatible with Java - but that means that if you use java.lang.Math in Java it will yield the same result as in Kotlin, not that different APIs (in this case java.lang.Math and kotlin.math) do exactly the same

Comment: @msrd0 Java and Kotlin don't round the same, as OP has pointed out.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No they don't, calling the same function in both languages yields the same result. Using different libraries might (and in this case will) behave differently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`kotlin.math.round`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/round.html)'s documentation says:

> Rounds the given value x towards the closest integer with ties rounded towards even integer.

So 152.5 is equally distant to 152 and 153, hence it is rounded to the closes even integer, i.e., 152.

On the other hand, Java's [`round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) says:

> Returns the closest long [or int, depending on the supplied argument] to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.

Looking at [`kotlin.math.round` source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.30/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/MathJVM.kt#L420), that function is just delegating the operation to Java's [`Math.rint(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-).

Comment: ...and Java's round says: " with ties rounding to positive infinity." - so both results are fine and expected.

Comment: I read the doc as well, my point is, kotlin.math is rounding down it to 152.0(Double) and Java.lang.Math is rounding up to 153(long). this kind of inconsistant behaviour is confusion for me.

Comment: @dhssa Kotlin also has `roundToInt`/`roundToLong` which uses Java's `round` method

Comment: kotlin.math != java.lang.Math so kotlin.math.round may follow a different spec than java.lang.Math.round() - just because they have the same name, doesn't mean they cannot follow different specs.

Comment: as @Sebastian said, the APIs are different, so it's normal to expect a different behavior. In theory you could create your own `math` library that rounds to the closest odd integer and that would be fine as well, assuming it is documented properly

Comment: @Sebastian, Stefan , OK, thanks for the clarification, the explanation has resolved my confusion now.

Comment: ~"**hence it is rounded to the closes even integer, i.e., 152.**". That is mathematically not correct.  We learned that in grade school.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky well, it depends on what you want to achieve. [Round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) strategy is meant to minimise " the expected error when summing over rounded figures, even when the inputs are mostly positive or mostly negative" (from Wikipedia)